# Adding the item numbers in an array and returning the total within a function

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me understand how to return the total of all the items in the array added together? Here is my code below:

```
var numbers = [7, 55, 99, 27, 3, 1];

function addThemUp(numeros) {
  for (var i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
  return numeros[i];
  }
}

addThemUp(numbers);
alert(addThemUp);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Add(`+`) each value in a `lopp` to a `variable` and return the `summed-variable`

```js
var numbers = [7, 55, 99, 27, 3, 1];

function addThemUp(numeros) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    total += numeros[i];
  }
  return total;
}

var op = addThemUp(numbers);
alert(op);
```

**Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)**

```js
var numbers = [7, 55, 99, 27, 3, 1];

function addThemUp(numeros) {
  return numeros.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });
}

var op = addThemUp(numbers);
alert(op);
```

Comment: I appreciate it @Rayon

Comment: @SaiaFonua, I'm glad it helped mate! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in the code in the alert calling, here is the one to do it.

```
var numbers = [7, 55, 99, 27, 3, 1];
function addThemUp(numeros) {
var total = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
total+=numeros[i];
  }
return total;
}

var t = addThemUp(numbers);
alert(t);
```